After setting 'compileSdk = 35', warning message about UI in Play Console
I am a developer using Android Studio. After compiling the app I developed with the targetSdk and compileSdk versions set to 35 and releasing the app, the following recommendation is displayed in the Play Console.

Your app uses deprecated APIs or parameters for wider screens One or
more of the APIs you are using or the parameters you set for
displaying wider screens and windows are deprecated in Android 15.
Your app uses the following deprecated APIs or parameters:
android.view.Window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows
android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor
android.view.Window.setNavigationBarColor
Here's where to start:
M.b.e


com.google.android.material.datepicker


e.o.a


e.p.a


e.q.a


f2.h.onCreate

I think this is related to the (full) screen UI on Android 15(SDK 35), so I deleted all the lines related to FitsSystemWindows and setStatusBarColor mentioned here from the xml of the app layout and changed the Material, but this warning continues.
Of course, this document was also carefully reviewed and applied.
If anyone has experience with this issue, I would appreciate some advice.
I'm using Android Studio Ladybug.
